# equivalence classes and minimal elemnts

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> $A = \{n | 2 \le n \le 12\}$
>
> $D$ is relation on $A$ defined: $(a,b) \in D$ iff $b \pmod{a} \equiv 0$.
>
> I need to find the elements which are minimal regarding to D.

---

What I think to do is to find all Equivalence Class and then take the minimal in each Equivalence Class. But here I think I miss something.

2 and 12 need to be in the same Equivalence Class, since 12 mod 2 === 0
2 and 10 need to be in the same Equivalence Class, since 10 mod 2 === 0

but each element can appear only in one Equivalence Class and so 2 => it mean that 2,10,12 need to be in the same class but 12 mod 10 !== 0

What I miss here?
thanks

Comment: This is not clear.  Your relation isn't an equivalence relation...$2\sim 4$ for instance, but $4\not \sim 2$.  So...what do you mean by an equivalence class?

Comment: As lulu pointed out, this is not an equivalence relation, but it is an order relation (in fact, there's a much easier way to describe this relation- recall the definition of modular congruence) so you can talk about minimal elements, i.e. elements $x$ such that if $(y,x)$, then $y=x$. If you're familiar with the idea of posets and Hasse diagrams, then draw the Hasse diagram for this poset and you'll see what the minimal element(s) are.

Comment: Thank for this clarification

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

To say that $b\equiv0\pmod a$ is equivalent to saying that $a\mid b$.  So, your relation is that $(a,b)\in D$ if and only if $a\mid b$.

So, what sort of element is minimal in this setup?  Being minimal means that a number isn't divisible by any number in $\{2,3,\ldots,12\}$ other than itself.